# ¿Como mostrar el valor de un Input en React con un state?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema. Tengo un componente React que permite editar un Input. Ese Input muestra el valor que viene de un state. Cuando se carga el input, se muestra el valor del state. Para dar un ejemplo, como caso inicial el state me retorna un 0, por lo que React renderiza el 0. Cuando presiono la barra de borrado, vuelve a ejecutar el evento onChange y me borra el valor, PERO, el value vuelve a traer el valor 0 por defecto, y nunca puedo borrar el numero del input.

Yo lo que quiero hacer es que, me deje cargar la cantidad de digitos que yo quiero pero que solo lo haga cuando saque el foco.

Encontre en internet que eso se puede hacer con onBlur. El problema es que con el onBlur, cuando cambio a otra pagina mediante un Routeo, vuelvo a la misma URL para renderizar el state anterior que almaceno redux, no me muestra el valor.

Este es el codigo con el onChange

```js
class ContentOption extends Component {
  ponerValor(numero) {
    if (numero == 0) {
      return '';
    } else return numero;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container id="contentoption">
        <Form>
          <FormGroup className="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              id="cantVariaciones"
              onClick={this.props.funcPermitir}
              defaultChecked={this.props.state.permitido}
            />
            <Label for="cantVariaciones">Generar Variaciones</Label>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Row>
              <Col sm={4} />
              <Col sm={4}>
                <Input
                  placeholder="Cantidad Variaciones"
                  id="cantVariation"
                  type="number"
                  onChange={this.props.funcVariaciones}
                  value={this.ponerValor(this.props.state.cantVariaciones)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm={4} />
            </Row>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ContentOption;
```

Este es el codigo con onBlur

```js
class ContentOption extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container id="contentoption">
        <Form>
          <FormGroup className="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              id="cantVariaciones"
              onClick={this.props.funcPermitir}
              defaultChecked={this.props.state.permitido}
            />
            <Label for="cantVariaciones">Generar Variaciones</Label>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Row>
              <Col sm={4} />
              <Col sm={4}>
                <Input
                  placeholder="Cantidad Variaciones"
                  id="cantVariation"
                  type="number"
                  onBlur={event => {
                    let aux = document
                      .getElementById('cantVariation')
                      .value(this.props.state.cantVariaciones);
                    this.props.funcVariaciones;
                   }}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm={4} />
            </Row>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ContentOption
```

En resumen. Si dejo el evento onChange, no puedo borrar el ultimo numero con la barra de borrado ya que me renderiza el ultimo valor del state. Si pongo el evento onBlur, me modifica el valor pero no puedo visualizarlo cuando vuelvo a la pagina en cuestion mediante Routeo

Comment: si logro entenderte, lo que deseas es que el input sea modificable normalmente sin embargo que el valor por defecto sea traído de otro componente o storage?

Comment: Exacto. El valor viene de un storage. El tema que si ese valor lo muestro en el value del input, cuando borro el ultimo digito, se me vuelve a renderizar el que estaba. Ej para el caso onChange: SI quiero borrar un 8, preciono la tecla de borrar, se modifica el state del storage, pero me vuelve a renderizar el 8, porque son valores enteros. Ahora para el caso onBlur, me deja borrar todos los digitos que quiero, porque no tengo el value = {state.valor}, pero al no tener eso, no me renderiza el valor del state. Si lo cambia en el store, pero no se visualiza en el input